# Scala how to use variable for join conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two `Seq[String]` variables containing my join keys for two different dataframes.

My problem is I don't know who do you pass these variables into the join. Here is what I have tried:

```
val listA = Seq("col1","col2","col3")
val listB = Seq("A","B","C")
df1.join(df2,df1(s"$listA")===df2(s"$listB"),"left")
```

And this is just not working because it's passing in "col1,col2,col3" instead of "col1","col2","col3"

I also tried this:

```
df1(listA:_*)
```

But it didn't work, giving errors.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example create a join expression:

```
df1.join(df2, 
  listA.zip(listB).map { case (x, y) => df1(x) === df2(y) }.reduce(_ && _))
```

or rename the columns to be matched on both sides:

```
listA.zip(listB).foldLeft(df1){ 
  case (df, (oldName, newName)) => df.withColumnRenamed(oldName, newName)
}.join(df2, listB)
```